# Is it possible to use an array for attribute comparison in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing jQuery code where I need to check if link is an image. Currently code looks like this:

```
$('a[href$=".png"]').click(function() {
    // do something smart
});
```

Is it possible to have an array of attributes in the code, to check for multiple formats, something like this:

```
$('a[href$=.jpg],a[href$=.jpeg],a[href$=.png]').click(function() {
    // do something even smarter
});
```

What is the best practice here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that.

That is perfectly legal.

---

What you can do also is check on click what the href is:

```
$('a').click(function(){
     var href = this.href;
     var hrefParts = href.split('.'); //array(0: fileName, ...length - 1: extension)
     if(hrefParts[hrefParts.length - 1] == 'png'){...}
     //etcetera...
});
```

Comment: Thanks Neal for fast reply and extra effort you put in.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is how you [group selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var ext = $(this).attr('href').substr('-4');
    if (ext == '.png' || ext == '.jpg') {
        ... continue ...
    }
});
```

Comment: This would fail if the image was a `.jpeg`.

Comment: @Bill That's why this is a code snippet and not a full example. It's to push him on his way, not to chew out the code for him. Any kid can use this set-up and modify it also to fit .jpeg's.

Comment: Understood. It could lead to some nasty code using substr() though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery a little more...

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
  var ext = $(this).attr('href').split('.').slice(-1);
  switch( ext ) {
    case 'png':
      // Code for PNGs!
    break;
    case 'jpg':
    case 'jpeg':
      // Code for JPGs!
    break;
    default:
      // Otherwise....
  }
});
```

Comment: where is this `return`ing to?

Comment: I just changed it. Bad habit of putting returns everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I would set up an object linking the extensions to the correct function.

Working off of Neal's example..

```
var extToFun = {
  png:function(){},
  gif:function(){}
};

$('a').click(function(){
     var href = this.href.split('.');
     var ext = href[hrefParts.length - 1];
    if(extToFun[ext])extToFun[ext].call(this);
});
```